# ruby (on rails) gem for basic form markup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'd like to add some basic markup (bbcode and so on) for an app I'm working on. I need not more than basic functionality such as [b], [url] and tags like that.

Can you recommend a gem that is easy to drop in?

EDIT:
I got a tip to use RDiscount, which is what I installed and am now trying to use. I am however unsure how to use it. My first idea was to use it in a :before_save filter in my model, but that means I would be saving the HTML to my database. This means if I want to edit the content there would be a bunch of HTML-tags showing for the user.

Another idea I had was to create a helper method in app/helpers/application_helper which would could return HTML to the views by calling helper_name(post.content). This would probably the best idea, and it seems to work (partially). Ruby on Rails still prevents any HTML to be "used" as it escapes the tags.

Do you recommend some other way to use it? If not, how can I "unescape" the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [RDiscount](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/), perhaps? Not clear what your requirements are, but here's [info about the project](http://tomayko.com/writings/ruby-markdown-libraries-real-cheap-for-you-two-for-price-of-one).

Comment: Another question. I'm not seeing any particular documentation about how to actually use this. I was thinking of using a :before_save filter and use .to_html to save it as html to the database, but that's probably not a good idea. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @eml, I'm probably not the right person to give you that advice. Sorry!

Comment: You should really make a new question, as your second question is easily lost under your edit, and makes it harder to search. To answer your question, don't save the HTML, just save the exact markdown input by the user. Then use .to_html for *displaying* the user input correctly formatted.

Comment: I was thinking about making a new post but I wasn't sure if it was the right thing to do or not. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) is a very popular and powerful plugin for this.

Comment: eml is asking for a way to allow the use of bbcode or other markups in a form field.  As far as i know, Formtastic does not includes anything for that.